# css overflow scroll bar appears even when there is nothing to scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using overflow:scroll like the code below, the issue I am having is that even if there is no text the scroll bar still shows.
 demo on w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow
you see that even if you cant scroll horizontally (left or right) there is still a scrolling bar. I am trying to have it where the scrollbar doesn't appear if there is nothing to scroll to.hope this makes sense

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
</style>
<p>overflow:scroll</p>
<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
```

Comment: I believe it is disabled in that demo because there is nothing to scroll?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you are looking for `overflow: auto`.

[Mozilla's Documentation on Overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> The overflow CSS property is shorthand for the overflow-x and overflow-y properties, and specifies what to do when content is too large to fit in its block formatting context.
>
> The options include clipping, showing scrollbars, or displaying the content flowing out of its container into the surrounding area.

**auto**

> Depends on the user agent. If content fits inside the padding box, it looks the same as visible, but still establishes a new block-formatting context. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
overflow: auto
```

The link you provided is really complicated. Here is everything explained, I think much better: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

Comment: Good link, I really like the information found on CSS-Tricks it's very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try `overflow: auto;`
so Scroll occurs depending on whether it is required or not automatically.

Use `overflow-x: auto` or `overflow-y: auto`
if you want to get automatic scroll bar for only one direction